# Video reading operation execution syncronization on matlab

Tags: matlab, video-processing, execution

I have these two lines

```
vid = 'videos/FL000071466.webm';
readerobj = VideoReader(vid);
vidFrames = read(readerobj);
```

and these lines sometimes work well but most of the time give this problem on console.

```
Error using VideoReader/read (line 86)
The frame range requested is beyond the end of the file.

Error in extraction (line 11)
vidFrames = read(readerobj);
```

but if I delete the ';' character from end of the `readerobj = VideoReader(vid);` and code start to output on console code working well.

I guess the reason is that  `vidFrames = read(readerobj);` line start to work before `readerobj = VideoReader(vid);` so it causes to read image before all the configuration has been made on readerobj.

How do you think I can solve that problem? Do I need to put a execution pause code between them?

Answer (score 0):

It is about the version that I am using currently. I need to use a version > 7.4 to have fully working matlab with videoreader object.